# Add Attribute to ActiveReccord after query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attr

This is what i trying to do: I have a User model with attributes :name, :lastame and :email. After a method like the following:

```
providers = User.find_by_sql [ query ]
```

I'd like all the users in providers to include a new attribute :location.

Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "include a new attribute"? Perhaps it would help if you could describe how you want to use the User objects afterward (and how it differs from how other User objects behave).

Comment: The difference is after find_by_sql i should be able to do @user.location. But not before find_by_sql.

Comment: What would `@user.location` return?

Comment: let's say count(some_column), from the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the easiest way will be to simply add the value you want as a column alias in your SELECT clause.

```
providers = User.find_by_sql "SELECT *, 'The Moon' AS location FROM users"
puts providers.first.location
# => "The Moon"
```